# PHP Magic Quotes adding slashes to template file?

Tags: php, magic-quotes

I have a default site template I use for my site like below:

```
<!-- Meta start -->
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!-- Meta end -->

<?php
    require_once($sidebar_inc);
?>

<?php
    // main.inc.php
    require_once($main_inc);
?>

<!-- CONTENT START -->
<?php
    // signup.tpl template location
    $tpl = 'inc/tpl/signup.tpl';
    // check if files exists and is readable
    if(file_exists($tpl) && is_readable($tpl)) {
        echo file_get_contents($tpl);
    } else {
        echo 'Template not found';
    }
?>

<!-- CONTENT FINISH -->

<?php
    // footer.inc.php
    require_once($footer_inc);
?>
```

Now my problem is when the `signup.tpl` is included via `file_get_contents` if magic quotes is on it adds `"\` to all the form data.

Here is the `signup.tpl` template

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<p>Welcome to SITE_NAME. To get started, you’ll need an account.</p>

<form action="signup.php" method="post">
    <div class="form_settings">
        <p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p>
        <p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p>
        <p><span>Message</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="your_enquiry"></textarea></p>
        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="submit" /></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Basically with magic quotes on it looks like this when the `signup.tpl` is included.

[image]

But with magic quotes off it does not add slashes so it looks as it should:

[image]

Now I know you should not have magic quotes on but I have a function to strip slashes if magic quotes is on from all `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION` so my scripts will work even if magic quotes is on. The problem is I don't know how to solve my problem that if magic quotes is on that it won't add slashes to the `signup.tpl`. I just want to make sure my script(s) will work if i for example moved it to a server which had magic quotes on.

What do I need to do to stop magic quotes adding slashes to the signup.tpl? I know I could just turn magic quotes off but like I said in case I changed server which had magic quotes on and did not allow to turn off magic quotes.

(Ignore the form, it is not a signup form just used as sample to show problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two magic quotes settings. From the manual:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
```

Magic-quotes-runtiume is not the same thing as magic GPC quoting - magic-quotes-runtime happens to all input at runtime, not just the GET/POST/COOKIE globals. You need to disable this setting at the start of your script:

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(false); # pre 5.3
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0); # 5.3 onwards
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply, much appreciated