# sql injection with rss feed

Tags: php, sql-injection

I think I have a small problem with mysqli injection. 
This article:

```
Filmster Jackie Chan heeft in Cannes zijn pensioen als actieheld aangekondigd. De 58-jarige acteur is naar eigen zeggen te oud om stunts uit te voeren en vindt de wereld "te gewelddadig". Jackie Chan is "heel, heel moe" na gedurende ...
```

Output in DB:

```
Filmster Jackie Chan heeft in Cannes zijn pensioen als actieheld aangekondigd. De 58-jarige acteur is naar eigen zeggen te oud om stunts uit te voeren en vindt de wereld \"te gewelddadig\". Jackie Chan is \"heel, heel moe\" na gedurende ...
```

As everybody can see there are some backslashes in it and i don't know how it comes.

**How I work?**
I dynamically load articles into the database with my url.

```
 echo " <a href='index.php?title=".$title."&content=".$article."&link=".$linkF."&klik="."test"."'>hier komt de link naar ...</a> ";
```

With the Superglobal variable _GET i drop them into variabeles and store them into the database with this script.

```
public function saveArticle() 
{
        include("connection.php");

            $sSql = "INSERT INTO tblArticles
                (titel, 
                article 
                ) 
                VALUES 
                ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sTitle) . "', 
                '" .mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $this -> m_sArticle) . "');";

        if (!$mysqli -> query($sSql))
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }

}
```

Comment: It is very likely that this is related to your PHP configuration (not a mysql injection), the related feature is: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php - disable those "magic" quotes and they will "magically" disappear again ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Magic Quotes adding slashes to template file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081035/php-magic-quotes-adding-slashes-to-template-file)