# Echo Print / Help Me

Tags: php, html, printing, echo

I Have a problem with Echo Print /

My code is:

```
<form  action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="hh">
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
$hh=$_POST[hh];
echo $hh;
?>
```

I'm enter In form

```
INSERT INTO `cq_action` VALUES ('5846', '5847', '5848', '0101', '0', 'H3');
```

Exmple

```
INSERT INTO `cq_action` VALUES (\'5846\', \'5847\', \'5848\', \'0101\', \'0\', \'H3\');
```

I need delete `\` In the output Please Help Me

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why the hell are you doing sql statements through a form input!? That's what phpmyadmin is for.

Comment: Is that all the processing you do on `$hh`? I tested as is and I don't get any slashes

Comment: Stripslashes will do the trick but I'll reiterate- don't try and reinvent the wheel- you'll end up with more bugs than is worth!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Magic Quotes adding slashes to template file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081035/php-magic-quotes-adding-slashes-to-template-file)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You use json_decode() to decode the escape characters. You can use str_replace('\', '',$str) to remove the \ character or any other character.

Comment: Why use json decode when there's a perfectly good strip slashes function?

Comment: stripslashes() and json_decode() do diffent things

Comment: Yes they do and your use of it is incorrect.